# Calculate Min/Max of sum of absolute sines

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, maxima-minima

I need to calculate as part of a proof the maximum and minimum of this function analytically:
$$f_n(\varphi) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left|\sin \left(\varphi-\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right) \right|$$
whereby $\varphi \in [0,2\pi)$.

I thought to try it with a complex approach, as it looks quite similar to root of unity. However, the absolute value makes me trouble in any simplification.

Comment: With Cauchy-Schwarz I get  $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left|\sin \left(\varphi-\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right) \right| \ge \left| \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin \left(\varphi-\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right) \right|  = 0 $ which seem for me by definition already case.

Comment: And for odd $n$ use the fact that $$f_n(\phi) = \frac{1}{2}f_{2n}(\phi)$$.

Comment: Note that $f_n(\varphi) = f_n(\varphi + \frac{2\pi}{n})$ so we can focus on the interval $\varphi \in [0,\frac{2\pi}{n})$. On this interval, for even numbers $n$ we have: $$f_n(\varphi) = 2\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\sin \left(\varphi-\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right) $$
Thus $f_n$ is differentiable on this interval and so the extrema are attained possibly at $0$ or the zeros of the derivative.  
$$f'_n(\phi) = 2\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\cos \left(\varphi-\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)$$ which is zero exactly at $\frac{\pi}{n}$.

Comment: Typo: I meant to write $f'_n(\varphi)$ instead of $f'_n(\phi)$ in the last equation.

Comment: Thank you, that helps much! And for odd n I can add use the same approach, right?

Comment: For odd $n$ you can't drop the absolute value of the $|\sin(\varphi - \frac{2\pi(n+1)/2}{n})|$ in the sum (even on our reduced interval) and so you can't differentiate the sum. I would rather do it the way I explained in the first comment - reducing it to the even $n$ case.